# SQL Server: how to query when the last transaction log backup has been taken?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, transaction-log

I would like to query for all databases (in SQL Server 2008 instance) date when the last transaction log backup has been taken. How to do that? I know that this information is somewhere, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT   d.name,
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date
FROM     master.sys.sysdatabases d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
         ON       b.database_name = d.name
         AND      b.type          = 'L'
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using this modified script so you can see which database is in FULL or BULK_LOGGED recovery model and not having any LOG BACKUP.

```
SELECT   d.name,
         d.recovery_model_desc,
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date
FROM     master.sys.databases d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
         ON       b.database_name = d.name
         AND      b.type          = 'L'
GROUP BY d.name, d.recovery_model_desc
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

Comment: Looking at the output of this statement, I see NULL for backup_finish_date... what does that mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050221/sql-server-what-exactly-is-the-backup-finish-date-in-master-sys-databases