# SQL Server: What exactly is the backup_finish_date in master.sys.databases

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

When querying for the last backup_finish_date with the following query (from [SQL Server: how to query when the last transaction log backup has been taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793805/sql-server-how-to-query-when-the-last-transaction-log-backup-has-been-taken)):

```
SELECT   d.name,
         d.recovery_model_desc,
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date
FROM     master.sys.databases d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
         ON       b.database_name = d.name
         AND      b.type          = 'L'
GROUP BY d.name, d.recovery_model_desc
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC
```

The backup_finish_date for all my databases is null, this is for DBs with a recovery mode of BULK_LOGGED, FULL or SIMPLE.

Does this imply that none of these databases has had their transaction log backed up (as suggested by the title of the linked question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You are correct. If your `backup_finish_date` is `null` means it was never backed up. However, `msdb..backupset` can be modified/tempered. You can check last backup of the database with backup type.

```
SELECT   d.name,
         d.recovery_model_desc,
         b.type, -- type of backup
         MAX(b.backup_finish_date) AS backup_finish_date
FROM     master.sys.databases d
         LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b
         ON       b.database_name = d.name
GROUP BY d.name, d.recovery_model_desc, b.type
ORDER BY backup_finish_date DESC

type Can be:
D = Database OR Full
I = Differential database
L = Log
F = File or filegroup
G =Differential file
P = Partial
Q = Differential partial
Can be NULL.
```

Refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to see if its possible to restore a table that I dropped. I'm assuming not? Once transaction logs have been truncated, are the log files saved?

Comment: You should have the backup available to restore the dropped table.